# Image not display in html img tag

Tags: php, ipa, image-compression

I working on ipa file which is ios app and I am trying to extract app's icon using php `IPA Distribution` and all things go fine , but when I trying to display that image into web browser the image can  not displayed  .
I think the image is compressed so I can not display it into web browser . so how can I decompress this image using php  to be able display it in to browser?
this is the code which I used to get image from ipa file

```
function getIcon ($ipa) {
//  $newstring = substr($dynamicstring, -7);
        $zip = zip_open($ipa);
        if ($zip) {
          while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {
            $fileinfo = pathinfo(zip_entry_name($zip_entry));//var_dump($fileinfo);//echo ($fileinfo['basename']);
            if ( strpos($fileinfo['basename'], '.png') ) {echo $fileinfo['filename'];
                $fp = fopen($this->folder.'/'.$fileinfo['basename'], "w");
                if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry, "r")) {
                  $buf = zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));
                  fwrite($fp,"$buf");
                  zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
                  fclose($fp);
                }
            $this->appicon = $this->folder."/".'image@3x.png';
            }
          }
          zip_close($zip);

    }
}
```

this code will extract image from ipa file and put it into image folder 
but when I trying to display that image using html code  like this

```
<img src="files/5ac5633052369/image@3x.png">
```

and I am sure about image's url

Comment: I downvoted. Please add the code whatever you have done so far for context. Then people can help you with the problem. We can do only random assumption with only text explanation.

Comment: thank you @HimanshuUpadhyay  I updated my question

Comment: You said, images is being saved in image folder. But you are passing path with files `<img src="files/5ac5633052369/image@3x.png">`. Can you mention the exact path of the image file?

Comment: Hi @Muh get image header pass like this header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

Comment: thank you for reply but not working

Comment: Can you check the file permission of the image?

Comment: yes and when I putting normal image into same folder that image is displayed successfully without any error into browser